# Are there compiling differences between Hexadecimal and Decimal numbers?

Tags: c#

```
int foo = 510;
int bar = 0x0001FE;
```

Are there  compiling differences between these two declarations?
For example, does your computer read these two values different?

Comment: You mean faster at compile time or run-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but Hex is clerer to read as human if you look for bit / byte values.

Internally all is binary and the compiler does convert it to binary representation anyway.